# How to add a fixed button over sencha touch carousel

Tags: sencha-touch, carousel

i am trying to use sencha touch(2.3) carousel component as my app's startup screen.

And i want to add 2 fixed  buttons on carousels - just as the enclosed pictures did(fixed means the button won't move with the carousel when user switch carousels).

i tried many approaches, but all failed - the 2 buttons will always moved with the carousel when user switch the carousels.

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

=== Updates ===

I add another pictures for comparing the carousel styles i made by touch and the target style i want to use.

=== Final Solution ===

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.Startup', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        xtype: 'main',
        requires: [
            'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
            'Ext.Button',
            'Ext.Container'
        ],
        config: {
            id: 'app-startup-view',
            layout: 'vbox',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            fullscreen: true,
            style: 'background: url("/resources/images/ss2_748x1024.jpg") no-repeat center',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'carousel',
                    id: 'startup-carousel',
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    align: 'center',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 'start-page-1',
                            bgimg: '/resources/images/ss2_748x1024.jpg',
                            html:'page-1'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'start-page-2',
                            bgimg: '/resources/images/ss3_748x1024.jpg',
                            html: 'page-2'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'start-page-3',
                            bgimg: '/resources/images/ss1_748x1024.jpg',
                            html: 'page-3'
                        }
                    ],
                    listeners: {//TODO: put this into the corresponding controller
                        activeitemchange: function (src, value, oldValue, eOpts) {
                            var view = src.up('#app-startup-view');
                            view.setStyle('background:url("' + value.bgimg + '") no-repeat center');
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'spacer'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'login-button',
                            flex: 1,
                            text: 'Login'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'register-button',
                            flex: 1,
                            text: 'Register'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'spacer'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]// items - solution 1
        }// config
    });
```

[image: pictures for demo the differences]

[image: carousel page 1]
[image: carousel page 2]
[image: carousel page 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the pictures the buttons are not part of the carousel. They are beneath it. So place them in an extra container.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.Carousel',
        'Ext.Button'
    ],

    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                height: "80%",
                items: [
                    {
                        html: 'test1'
                    },
                    {
                        html: 'test2'
                    },
                    {
                        html: 'test3'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtpye: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'button1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'button2'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer'
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you very much. But the carousel style in your answer is very different with the one in my questions. i post another pictures for demo the differences

Comment: Sure it is. My demo code only demonstrates how to get the buttons beneath the carousel. Nothing more nothing less. Styling is a totally different questions. If you want to get a background image like in the pictures you have to set the image as background of the container that contains the carousel and the button. Every time the active item of the carousel changes you have to change the background image of the parent container.

Comment: thanks Martin, you are right :) i finally made the carousel works as my expected by following your suggestion~~